# Slow network speed until restart of PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, performance

I have a strange problem that I cannot figure out.

After a day or or two my network slows right down from 64Mbps to around 3Mbps, restarting the router only gives it a boost up to around 5Mbps but the only way I know how fix the speed problem is by restarting my pc and then after the restart its back up to around 64Mbps again.

Also I knotice when its going slow that sound coming from the speakers is robotic and my computer goes sluggish even tho the RAM and CPU usage is low.

I have tried resolving without a pc restart by using flushdns and release/renew and that dosent speed things up.

Why and how does restarting my pc fix this? Shouldnt a simple restart of the router be enough as that is the device that is handling allthe packets

**PC Specs**

OS: Win 10 Pro

CPU: Intel Core i7 3770

RAM: 8gb

Antivirus & Firewall: Bitdefender Total Security 2016

Connection type: Ethernet $ only two other people using it with their phones only

Normal connection speed when running fine: 60Mbps

Connection speed when problem exists: 1 - 3Mbps

When the network is slow I even stop my torrents and it still continues.

Last time it happened (2 hours ago) my CPU was at 27% and RAM was at 20%

Comment: Could you add your OS to the post as it could be a Factor in the Answer.

Comment: What background programs are you running, eg: torrents, audio/video streaming? What OS and PC are you using?

Comment: What about network utilization during these slowdowns (you can see it in the task manager on the performance tab)?

Comment: thats a good idea il have a look next time it happens

Comment: Do you have any firewalls and antiviruses on your PC?

Comment: Wireless or wired connection?

Comment: Also what is your total speed of the connection. And are you the only one using it?